# 3 way partition of cartesian product

Tags: combinatorics

Given ordered set $X$ and $Y$, we construct set $Z = X \times Y$.
The cardinalities are $|X| = m, |Y| = n, |Z| = m*n$.

There are $3^{m*n}$ different three-way partitions of $Z$, denote $P(Z)$.

If we define a new partition strategy of $Z$, which partition based on $X$ first, then pick one side and partition based on $Y$, denote $Q(Z) $. First, would the partition result in the same as $P(Z)$ ?

What's the cardinality of $Q(Z)$?

Answer (score 0):

The cardinality of $P(Z)$ is $3^{m*n}$, because every element in $Z$ get to decide to be in $(1, 2, 3)$ partitions.

While cardinality of $Q(Z)$ is $2^m*2^n = 2^{m+n}$. Since there are $2^m$ ways of making the first partition, and since $Z$ is a cartesian product of $X$ and $Y$, both sides would have all $Y$, so basically there are $2^n$ ways to make a new partition.